# Does storing mpi rank enhance the performance

Tags: c, performance, mpi, rank

In a legacy code base the rank of a `mpi` application is stored in a struct. Whenever the rank is checked the rank is being read from this struct, instead of calling `MPI_Comm_rank`.

I see some problems with this approach, namely:

- The struct and `MPI_Comm_rank` need to be synchronised. Errors will occur if the struct and `MPI_Comm_rank` do not contain the same value of rank.
- The struct need to be either global or is passed as an argument to every function in need of the rank.
- Readability of the code is decreased.

Thus, I like to get rid of it.

My question is, if this approach is enhancing the performance? Has anyone experience how long a call of `MPI_Comm_rank` is in comparison with reading the value form a struct?

I tried using `google benchmark`, but both are so quick, that I can not tell the difference.

Comment: You are basically saying that you profiled your application, and found no reason for using caching, and now want somebody to tell you whether you should cache anyway?

Comment: He is saying someone else implemented caching a while ago, and he is now wondering if this was really necessary.

Comment: keep in mind the rank of a task within a communicator never changes, so you need to keep tracks of communicators, but do not have to worry of maintaining "cache coherency".

Comment: @Groo I performed a benchmark of a small unit test with the two implementations to get the rank. The runtime of the test is ridiculously small. Thus, the benchmark is disturbed with noise and I think it is not trustworthy. My question is, if in a real application this will have an effect.

Comment: It should not. Your app should call `MPI_Comm_rank()`, which is a local operation, less often than MPI subroutines that perform communication, and the latter are order of magnitude slowers.

Comment: @schorsch312 could you please accept my answer if you think it's relevant for your question? Otherwise, can you leave a comment to it in order to discuss this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze the `MPI_Comm_rank` function:

This is the code (taken from [this](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/1e2019ce2a903be24361b3424d8e98d27e941c6c/ompi/mpi/c/comm_rank.c) source):

```
int MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_Comm comm, int *rank)
{
    MEMCHECKER(
        memchecker_comm(comm);
    );

    OPAL_CR_NOOP_PROGRESS();

    if ( MPI_PARAM_CHECK ) {
        OMPI_ERR_INIT_FINALIZE(FUNC_NAME);

        if (ompi_comm_invalid (comm))
            return OMPI_ERRHANDLER_INVOKE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERR_COMM,
                                          FUNC_NAME);

        if ( NULL == rank )
            return OMPI_ERRHANDLER_INVOKE(comm, MPI_ERR_ARG,
                                          FUNC_NAME);
    }

    *rank = ompi_comm_rank((ompi_communicator_t*)comm);
    return MPI_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the code of the `ompi_comm_rank` function (taken from [this](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/ec1a9a8218baedbd2a84966fbf7bc522d981a936/ompi/communicator/communicator.h) source):

```
static inline int ompi_comm_rank(ompi_communicator_t* comm)
{
    return comm->c_my_rank;
}
```

As you can see, there are some sanity checks that are being performed in that function before returning the actual value of the rank (that is also stored in a struct), which will definitely generate an overhead if you do a serious benchmark.

On a real case scenario, if you have a really high volume of rank queries, `MPI_Comm_rank` will be *slower* than just fetching a field from a struct. However, I don't think that the time difference between the solutions will be significantly big.

Comment: Note the sanity checks can (likely) be disabled at configure or run time.